# Insert into table without having to specify every column value for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I insert into a table where the number of column value supplied is different for each row. If there is no value for a column.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (column1 VARCHAR(5), column2 VARCHAR(5), column3 VARCHAR(5),
column4 VARCHAR(5), column5 VARCHAR(5), column6 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO myTable ('A','B','C','D'),('A','B','C'),('A','B'),('A'),
('B','C','D'),('C','D','A')
```

I am fully aware of having the each row inserted by using NULL for the column that is empty.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
INSERT INTO myTable ('A','B','C','D',NULL,NULL),('A','B','C',NULL,NULL,NULL),
('A','B',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),('A',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('B','C','D',NULL,NULL,NULL),('C','D','A',NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Is there a way to insert each row without having to specifying the column as NULL if there column value is not supplied?

Comment: If not specify the value of all of the columns,you must specify the column name. Where is the data source of updating. you can insert row with column1 with 'A'.  Then update other column if it had been specified value

Answer (score 2):

You can insert them separately:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) values ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3) values ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F');
insert into mytable (col3, col4) values ('C', 'D');
```